# Using Class Based View UpdateView with a 2 primary keys model

Tags: python, django

I'm building an aplication with two primary keys (it's a legacy database).

Basically what I want to do is to click on table element and redirect to another page based on the primary keys on the model.

I'm not finding anything about how to do this with Django Class Based Views

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class RmDadoscarteira(models.Model):
    dtcalculo = models.DateField(db_column='dtCalculo', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cdcarteira = models.CharField(db_column='cdCarteira', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nmcarteira = models.CharField(db_column='nmCarteira', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pl = models.FloatField(db_column='PL', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    retornocota1d = models.FloatField(db_column='RetornoCota1d', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    var = models.FloatField(db_column='Var', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    var_lim = models.FloatField(db_column='VaR_Lim', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    var_variacao1d = models.FloatField(db_column='VaR_Variacao1d', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    var_variacao63d = models.FloatField(db_column='VaR_Variacao63d', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    var_consumolimite = models.FloatField(db_column='VaR_ConsumoLimite', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    stress = models.FloatField(db_column='Stress', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    stress_lim = models.FloatField(db_column='Stress_Lim', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    stress_variacao1d = models.FloatField(db_column='Stress_Variacao1d', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    stress_variacao63d = models.FloatField(db_column='Stress_Variacao63d', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    stress_consumolimite = models.FloatField(db_column='Stress_ConsumoLimite', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    grupo = models.CharField(db_column='Grupo', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    var_pl = models.FloatField(db_column='VaR_PL', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    stress_pl = models.FloatField(db_column='Stress_PL', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.


    objetos = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'RM_DadosCarteira'
        unique_together = (('dtcalculo', 'cdcarteira'),)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import *
import json
import pandas as pd
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

# View do relatorio Flagship Solutions
#def FlagshipSolutions(request):
#    render(request, 'dash_solutions_completo.html')

class VisualizaFundoSolutions(UpdateView):
    template_name = "prototipo_fundo.html"
    model = RmDadoscarteira
    context_object_name = 'fundos_metricas'
    fields = 'all'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("portal_riscos:dash_solutions")





def FlagshipSolutions(request):

    # Queryset Tabela Diaria
    query_carteira = RmDadoscarteira.objetos.filter(grupo='Abertos')
    # Data Mais recente
    dt_recente = str(query_carteira.latest('dtcalculo').dtcalculo)
    # Filtrando queryset para data mais recente
    query_carteira = query_carteira.filter(dtcalculo=dt_recente)


    # Preparando os dados para o grafico de utilizacao de var e stress
    util_var = [round(obj['var_consumolimite'] * 100,2) for obj in query_carteira.values()]
    util_stress = [round(obj['stress_consumolimite'] * 100,2) for obj in query_carteira.values()]

    # Queryset Historico Graficos
    ### Definir um filtro de data
    query_hist = RmHistoricometricas.objetos.filter(grupo='Abertos').filter(dtcalculo__gte='2018-07-11')
    ### Queryset temporario ate dados de retorno e var estarem iguais
    query_data = RmHistoricometricas.objetos.filter(grupo='Abertos').filter(dtcalculo__gte='2018-07-11').filter(info='% VaR')

    ## Data Frames de Saida

    # Data Frame Historico
    df_hist = pd.DataFrame(list(query_hist.values()))
    # Criando uma chave de concateno
    df_hist['concat'] = df_hist['dtcalculo'].astype(str) + df_hist['cdcarteira']
    df_hist['valor'] = round(df_hist['valor'] * 100, 2)



    # Data Frame VaR PL Historico
    df_hist_var = df_hist[df_hist['info']=='% VaR']
    # Data Frame Stress PL Historico
    df_hist_stress = df_hist[df_hist['info']=='% Stress']
    # Data Frame Consumo VaR
    df_hist_var_cons = df_hist[df_hist['info']=='% Utilização Limite VaR']
    # Data Frame Consumo Stress
    df_hist_stress_cons = df_hist[df_hist['info']=='% Utilização Limite Stress']
    # Data Frame de Retorno
    df_hist_ret = df_hist[df_hist['info']=='Retorno']


    # Obtendo todas as datas (removendo duplicados)
    #datas = df_hist.dtcalculo.drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)
    datas = pd.DataFrame(list(query_data.values()))
    datas =  datas.dtcalculo.drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)

    # Obtendo o nome de todos os fundos (removendo duplicados)
    fundos = list(df_hist.cdcarteira.drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index(drop=True))

    # Criando um data frame unico com todas as informacoes a serem utilizadas
    df_hist_saida = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dtcalculo', 'cdcarteira'])

    # Criando um data frame com o numero de linhas igual a fundos * datas
    for fundo in fundos:
        # Data Frame temporario
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dtcalculo', 'cdcarteira'])
        # Copiando as datas
        df_temp['dtcalculo'] = datas
        # Inserindo o nome do fundo
        df_temp['cdcarteira'] = [fundo] * len(datas)

        # Inserindo dados do temp no data frame de saida
        df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.append(df_temp)


    # Resetando index e criando uma chave de concateno para o dataframe de saida
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_hist_saida['concat'] = df_hist_saida['dtcalculo'].astype(str) + df_hist_saida['cdcarteira']

    # Criando coluna de var pl
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.merge(df_hist_var[['concat', 'valor']], on='concat', how='left')
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.rename(columns={'valor': 'var_pl'})

    # Criando coluna de var pl
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.merge(df_hist_stress[['concat', 'valor']], on='concat', how='left')
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.rename(columns={'valor': 'stress_pl'})

    # Criando coluna de consumo var
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.merge(df_hist_var_cons[['concat', 'valor']], on='concat', how='left')
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.rename(columns={'valor': 'var_cons'})

    # Criando coluna de consumo stress
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.merge(df_hist_stress_cons[['concat', 'valor']], on='concat', how='left')
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.rename(columns={'valor': 'stress_cons'})

    # Criando coluna de retorno
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.merge(df_hist_stress_cons[['concat', 'valor']], on='concat', how='left')
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.rename(columns={'valor': 'retorno'})

    # Removendo a coluna concatenado
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.drop('concat', axis=1)

    # Substituindo NaN por none
    df_hist_saida = df_hist_saida.fillna('None')

    # Criando dicionarios de saida
    dict_var_pl_hist = dict()
    dict_stress_pl_hist = dict()
    dict_var_cons_hist = dict()
    dict_stress_cons_hist = dict()

    for fundo in fundos:
        dict_var_pl_hist[fundo] = list(df_hist_saida[df_hist_saida['cdcarteira'] == fundo].var_pl)
        dict_stress_pl_hist[fundo] = list(df_hist_saida[df_hist_saida['cdcarteira'] == fundo].stress_pl)
        dict_var_cons_hist[fundo] = list(df_hist_saida[df_hist_saida['cdcarteira'] == fundo].var_cons)
        dict_stress_cons_hist[fundo] = list(df_hist_saida[df_hist_saida['cdcarteira'] == fundo].stress_cons)


    # Lista contendo todas as datas utilizadas
    lista_datas = list(datas.astype(str))

    # Alertas
    alerta_1 = [70] * len(datas)
    alerta_2 = [85] * len(datas)
    alerta_3 = [100] * len(datas)

    # Flagship
    context ={'query_carteira': query_carteira,
              'fundos': json.dumps(fundos),
              'util_var': json.dumps(util_var),
              'util_stress': json.dumps(util_stress,),
              'dict_var_pl_hist': json.dumps(dict_var_pl_hist, default=dict),
              'dict_stress_pl_hist': json.dumps(dict_stress_pl_hist, default=dict),
              'dict_var_cons_hist': json.dumps(dict_var_cons_hist, default=dict),
              'dict_stress_cons_hist': json.dumps(dict_stress_cons_hist, default=dict),
              'datas_hist': json.dumps(lista_datas, default=str),
              'alerta_1': json.dumps(alerta_1),
              'alerta_2': json.dumps(alerta_2),
              'alerta_3': json.dumps(alerta_3),
    }



    return render(request, 'dash_solutions_completo.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
# Importamos a função index() definida no arquivo views.py

from portal_riscos.views import *
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView


app_name = 'portal_riscos'

# urlpatterns contém a lista de roteamento URLs


urlpatterns = [
    # Dashboard Solutions
    path('', FlagshipSolutions, name='dash_solutions'),
    path('solutions_fundos/<pk>/<cdcarteira>', VisualizaFundoSolutions.as_view(), name='solutions_fundos')


    ]
```

Part of the table where I want to click and redirect

```
<a href="{% url 'portal_riscos:solutions_fundos' fundo.dtcalculo fundo.cdcarteira %}"
                                                        class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Atualizar</a>
```

That's the error that I've got:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/solutions_fundos/2019-01-14/FICFI52865

Django Version: 2.1.2
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'portal_riscos',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'django.contrib.humanize']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  189.         self.object = self.get_object()

File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_object
  52.             obj = queryset.get()

File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  403.             (self.model._meta.object_name, num)

Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned at /solutions_fundos/2019-01-14/FICFI52865
Exception Value: get() returned more than one RmDadoscarteira -- it returned 21!
```

Anyone has any idea about what can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't specifically related to having two primary keys. If you need to get an object in a class based view other than with the basic pk or slug lookup, you need to define the `get_object` method.

```
class VisualizaFundoSolutions(UpdateView):
    ...
    def get_object(self):
        return RmDadoscarteira.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"], cdcarteira=self.kwargs["cdcarteira"])
```